# Why is there a space/tab in the last line after I finished the theorem?

Tags: spacing, equations

When I finish the theorem section the next line is not lined up properly.

This is seen in:

```
\newtheorem*{them}{\textcolor{OliveGreen}{Theorem}}
```

[image]

```
\begin{them}
\textcolor{OliveGreen}{Pythagoras}\\
There no rational number whose square is 2.
\begin{pf}
Any rational number $r=\frac{p}{q}$ where $p.q\in\mathbb{Z}, q\neq 0$. in particular one can assume that p.q have no common factors.\\
(by contradiction) supposed $\exist r$ such that $r^2=l$\\
$\frac{p^2}{q^2}=2$, then\\
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{split}
            p^2 =2q^2 &\Longrightarrow \text{p is even} \\
            &\Longrightarrow p=2k \qquad \text{for some } k\in\mathbb{Z}\\
            &\Longrightarrow p^2=(2k)^2=4k^2\\
            &\Longrightarrow 2q^2=4k^2\\
            &\Longrightarrow q^2 = 2k^2\\
            &\Longrightarrow \text{q is even}\\
            &\Longrightarrow \text{both p.q are even}\\
            &\Longrightarrow \text{p and q have a common factor, namely 2. which is a contradiction}.\\
    \end{split}

\end{equation*}
\Longrightarrow \text{conclude that no rational number squared equals to 2}
\end{pf}
\end{them}

$\mathbb{N} =\{1,2,3,...\}$\\
$\mathbb{Z} =\{...-2,-1,0, 1,2...\}$\\
```

Comment: The next thing after a theorem is assumed to be a new paragraph.  In your example this is reinforced by the presence of a blank line in the source.  The indentation is merely an ordinary paragraph indent.  You can suppress it by inserting `\noindent`, but somehow this doesn't seem quite what you probably want.  Also, it's not the best practice to embed a proof within a theorem.  It's not clear what theorem package you're using, but none of them (that I'm aware of) recommends that.

Comment: I used the one I find online that do not number the theorems and added the colour. 
``````
\newtheorem*{them}{\textcolor{OliveGreen}{Theorem}}
``````